# Show that function is uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

The function is defined as $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
I now inserted the function into the definition for uniformly continuous functions and got an expression like
$\delta \cdot \frac{1}{(1+|x|)(1+|x_0|)}=\epsilon $.

How can i go on to estimate a value for $\epsilon$?

Comment: You want to get a value for $\delta$ and it is enough if we get one that satisfies $\delta\cdot\frac{1}{(1+|x|)(1+|x_0|)}\leq\delta\cdot\frac{1}{1\cdot 1}<\epsilon$, where the first inequality is always true. Therefore, any $\delta$ that is positive and smaller than $\epsilon$ will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|f(x)-f(y)|= |\frac{|x|-|y|}{(1+|x|)(1+|y|)} | \le | |x|-|y|| \le |x-y|.$$